# How do I route from internal clients to internal services on openbsd?

Tags: networking, local-area-network

I have a domain `my.domain` which I would like to point to my WAN, which in turn port forwards to an internal server.

With my current setup, external users can connect to `my.domain`, but local users cannot. How do I make it so `my.domain` gets routed internally?

This is how my internal network looks like:

```
         .----------.
         | Internet |
         '----------'
               ^
               | em0
               |
  .-------------------------.
  | OpenBSD Router          |      em2
  | 192.168.1.1 - my.domain |<-------------.
  '-------------------------'              |
           ^                               |
           | em1                  .----------------.
           |                      | managed switch |
   .----------------.             '----------------'
   | Gigabit Switch |<--------.
   '----------------'         |
           ^                  |
           |                  |
   .--------------.    .--------------.
   | Docker VM    |    | unifi wap    |
   | 192.168.1.10 |    | 192.168.1.30 |
   '--------------'    '--------------'
```

and here is my `pf.conf`:

```
#------------------------------#
# set up macros #
#------------------------------#

ext_if="em0"

int_if="em1"
dmz_if="em2"
localnet = "{ em1:network, em2:network }"

docker_vm="192.168.1.10"

table <martians> { 0.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 127.0.0.0/8 192.0.0.0/24 192.0.2.0/24 }
webports = "{ http, https }"

#------------------------------#
# protect and block by default #
#------------------------------#

set skip on lo0
match in all scrub (max-mss 1440)

# spoofing protection for all ifaces
antispoof quick for { $int_if $dmz_if }
block in from no-route
block in quick from urpf-failed

# block non-routable private addrs
block in quick on $ext_if from <martians> to any
block return out quick on $ext_if from any to <martians>

# default block all traffic on all lan nics from any pc/device
block return in on { $int_if $dmz_if }

# block all traffic on ext interface from the internet
block drop in log on $ext_if

# allow ICMP
match in on $ext_if inet proto icmp icmp-type { echoreq } tag ICMP_IN
block drop in on $ext_if proto icmp
pass in proto icmp tagged ICMP_IN max-pkt-rate 100/10
pass in on $ext_if inet proto icmp icmp-type { 3 code 4, 11 code 0 }

# allow NICs to pass data thru ethernet port
pass out inet

#------------------------------#
# internal lan #
#------------------------------#

# allows any pc on $int_if to send data thru NICs ethernet
pass in on $int_if

# block dns queries not addressed to our dns server
block return in quick on $int_if proto { udp tcp } to ! $int_if port { 53 853 }

#------------------------------#
# dmz lan rules #
#------------------------------#

# allows any pc on $int_if to send data thru NICs ethernet
pass in on $dmz_if

# block dns queries not addressed to our dns server
block return in quick on $dmz_if proto { udp tcp } to ! $int_if port { 53 853 }

#------------------------------#
# NAT #
#------------------------------#

pass out on $ext_if inet from $localnet to any nat-to ($ext_if)

#------------------------------#
# Redirects #
#------------------------------#

pass in proto tcp to $ext_if port ssh

# ???
pass in on $ext_if inet proto tcp to $ext_if port $webports rdr-to $docker_vm tag RDR
pass in on $int_if inet proto tcp from $localnet to $docker_vm port $webports
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up solving it, although I'm unsure if there's a better way than manually specifying each dns record via `unbound`.

I edited unbound's config (`/var/unbound/etc/unbound.conf`), and added some `local-data` policies:

```
server:
    local-zone: "my.domain." static
    local-data: "my.domain. IN A 192.168.1.10"
    local-data: "sub1.my.domain. IN A 192.168.1.10"
    local-data: "sub2.my.domain. IN A 192.168.1.10"
```

and then restarted unbound with `rcctl restart unbound`.

Now when I do `traceroute` I get:

```
traceroute to sub1.my.domain (192.168.1.10), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10)  1.348 ms  1.299 ms  1.278 ms
```

Comment: this is not an answer to your own q-n because your asked as "with pf".

Comment: Apologies, edited my question. I really meant to ask how I can achieve it on opensbd. If someone knows of a pf-only answer, that would be nice but unbound solves this for me.

Comment: sure, what you've done is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS and isn't any specific to OpenBSD either. Since it works for you I think it's ok to skip pf's use